# hp-ux admin tool lsof fuser for B.11.31

Tags: administration, hp-ux

```
centrpt:oracle> uname -r
B.11.31
```

We need lsof and fuser as there are unclosed file handler so we cannot reclaim disk space after reboot. Where we can get the tool for this dated version of HP-UX ??

Answer (score 0):

You can download lsof and many other opensource tools from http://hpux.connect.org.uk/

I recommend you to download depothelper first: http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Sysadmin/depothelper-2.00/

It will take care of dependencies and will download all packages needed for a certain tool. Read the help of the command.